# How to remove a first character form a line matching a specific pattern using sed in linux

Tags: linux

I want to remove a first character from a line matching particular string.
for example.
I want to remove '#' from the following line which have text user in it.

'#I am a user'.

Comment: We expect our users to do some research before asking a question.  What research have you done?   What have you learned?

Answer (score 0):

For example, this should do the trick:

```
cat myfile | sed -r '/user/ s/.(.*)/\1/'
```

Comment: how to update "myfile' with it

Comment: Can you explain the syntax? so your answer is more than just a source for copy-pasting in [voodoo programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming). `<myfile sed '/user/ s/.//'` is simpler. In what aspects (if any) is your command better?